# Options For Samsung Galaxy S5 ACTIVE "SMG870W"- Users with Custom Rom compatibility?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.4-kitkat, samsung

I was wondering,besides any opinions based on the judgment of my decision to buy a Samsung Galaxy ACTIVE version of the S "SM-G870W", can the Samsung S5 Active be Flashed with any ROms, specifically Cyanogenmod or even lollipop, I would prefer to be able to access different choices, and would be very grateful for some advice,personal experience and/ or some ideas to allow for the most innovative experience in the function and user interface of my SM-G870W. 
     My PHONE IS ROOTED, running 4.4.2 kitkat, 3.4.0-3084104 kernal build.I believe, I used Odin, as well as Helium to Backup previous, and the App SuperSU is in my app list and along with Odin's "success" sign and no obvious errors or malfunctions i believe the root is in good condition. Carrier is Bell Canada.

Comment: Here is at least one option, I am a noob so excuse me if you already knew this. the other answers didn't seem helpful. https://forum.xda-developers.com/att-galaxy-s5/development/rom-s5-active-complete-stock-4-4-2-t2855455